# How to make a DIV scrollable instead of BODY?

Tags: html, css

I want my page's BODY ***not to be*** scrollable but a DIV inside the BODY should be scrollable.
I have this in my css file:

---

```
body {
overflow:hidden
}

.mainSection {
overflow:scroll
}
```

---

but it doesn't work and the DIV doesn't become scrollabel (it just shows two disabled scroll bars for the DIV)!

Answer (score 29):

`.mainSection` needs to have a `height`. Otherwise the browser can not know what it should consider `overflow`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the style for your `mainSection` class is being applied? You can use a tool like [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (for Firefox) to make sure that the style is being correctly applied. Also if you just have one mainSection, you might want to use an id instead of a class. the tag in html would then be `<div id="mainSection">` instead of `<div class="mainSection">` and the css becomes `#mainSection { ... }` instead of `.mainsection { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the whole thing well explained

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp
You can experiment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before, but I could manage to solve it just with `overflow: auto;`. Try it and it will work. 
**Updated**
The full html code looks like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #scrollable_div{
            overflow: auto;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border: solid thin black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>        
    <div id="scrollable_div">my div text</div>
</body>
```

**Works perfectly in any browsers. I tested myself in *Chrome, IE, Safari, Mozilla, and Opera***